# Facebook 'apprequests' method and Requests Dialog

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I need to redirect back to my website after sending the invitation to friends using Requests Dialog.The code that I used is

```
function newInvite(){
             var receiverUserIds = FB.ui({ 
                    method : 'apprequests',
                    message: 'Come on man checkout my applications. visit http://ithinkdiff.net',
             },
             function(receiverUserIds) {
                      console.log("IDS : " + receiverUserIds.request_ids);
                    }
             );
```

I am using new php sdk(3.0).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you just need to know who invited whom, you dont need this. this info you can get when the invited users klicks the request and comes to your page, you can read out the request (which you need todo to delete them anyways), and there you have the uid of the sending and the receiving user.

Comment: @rufinus I didn't know that was possible. I was under the impression Facebook ruled out & provide it in a way so that nobody can track invitations. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/acX5tvKu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I am sorry, I think I misunderstood. You are trying to catch recipient IDs here right?

---

Though you have stated PHP SDK, but your code is using JS SDK. Here is how you can do it in JS:

```
FB.ui({
    method:'apprequests',
    message:'I want you to try this app',
    // to:123456798, // for sending to specific users
    // filters:['app_non_users'], // commented: let users send notifications to app users too, probably a good idea to make them revisit?
    data:'' // send data what you would like to track, FB will send that back in the URL for us
});
```